# Matplot lib plot for line plot(python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line plot from 2 columns of a data frame

- Column 1: index ranging from 1 to 200000
- Column 2: counter ranging from 100 to 30,000
- X axis: column 1
- Y axis: column 2

Just plotting with pyplot does not really show the progression of values

Is there a better way to control column 1 and 2 such that it starts with low number 1-10, 10-100, 100-1000, 1000-2000, 5000-10000 And so on ?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't really show the progression of values?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the graph you're getting so it is easier to understand?

Comment: Also could you post the code for plotiing?